# Python: How to test multiple values inside an if [multiple values] in list:

Tags: python

I have returned a list of href values from a HTML document. I want to go though every link within this list and test to see if they contain any of the values within my `IMAGE_FORMAT` tuple.

```
IMAGE_FORMAT = (
    '.png',
    '.jpg',
    '.jpeg',
    '.gif',
)
```

At present I am simply testing for `'.jpg'` e.g  `if '.jpg' in link.get('href'):`

I'd like to extend this code to something along the lines of `if [any value inside IMAGEFORMAT] in link.get('href'):`

What would be the most efficient or cleanest way or doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want `in`, then maybe

```
href = link.get('href')
if any(end in href for end in IMAGE_FORMAT):
    # do something
    pass
```

but if you actually want `ends with`, then use `.endswith`:

```
>>> IMAGE_FORMAT = ('.png','.gif','.jpg','.jpeg')
>>> 'fred.gif'.endswith(IMAGE_FORMAT)
True
```

Depends on how you want to treat 'fred.gif.gz', etc.  Also note you might want to work with href.lower() if you don't care about case.

Comment: I always find myself tempted to write `any('fred.gif'.endswith(ending) for ending in IMAGE_FORMAT)`, neglecting that `.endswith` already accepts `*args` to do what I want. x.x

Comment: You mention _If you really want in, then maybe..._ would there be a nicer way of writing the same code?

Answer (score 1):

Try `any` against list comprehension.

```
any(e in href for e in IMAGE_FORMAT)
```

Or, in English, "are any of the items in my image formats in my URI?"  Bare in mind how `in` functions with strings, though.

Comment: No need for the list. `any(e in href for e in IMAGE_FORMAT)` will do fine.